# Python loop freezing with no error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a code in Python that shows the number of steps needed to reach one from any number using a simple algorithm. This is my code:

```
print('Enter the lowest and highest numbers to test.')
min = input('Minimum number: ')
min = int(min)
max = input('Maximum number: ')
max = int(max) + 1
print(' ')
for n in range(max - min):
    count = 0
    num = n
    while not num == 1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num / 2
        else:
            num = (num * 3) + 1
    count = count + 1
    print('Number: '+str(int(n)+min)+'   Steps needed: '+count)
```

It freezes up without showing an error message, and I have no clue why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are invoking `range()` incorrectly.

Your code: `for n in range(max - min):` produces the range of numbers starting at `0` and ending at the value `max-min`. Rather, you want the range of numbers starting at `min` and ending at `max`.

Try this:

```
for n in range(min, max):
```

2) You are performing floating-point division, but this program should use only integer division. Try this:

```
num = num // 2
```

3) You are updating the `count` variable in the wrong loop context. Try indenting it one stop.

4) Your final line could be:

```
print('Number: '+str(n)+'   Steps needed: '+str(count))
```

Program:

```
print('Enter the lowest and highest numbers to test.')
min = input('Minimum number: ')
min = int(min)
max = input('Maximum number: ')
max = int(max) + 1
print(' ')
for n in range(min, max):
    count = 0
    num = n
    while not num == 1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num // 2
        else:
            num = (num * 3) + 1
        count = count + 1
    print('Number: '+str(n)+'   Steps needed: '+str(count))
```

Result:

```
Enter the lowest and highest numbers to test.
Minimum number: 3
Maximum number: 5

Number: 3   Steps needed: 7
Number: 4   Steps needed: 2
Number: 5   Steps needed: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's getting stuck in the `while not num == 1` loop.  Remember that `range()` starts at 0, so num is first set to 0, which is divisible by 2, and so will be reset to 0/2... which is 0 again!  It will never reach 1 to break the loop.

EDIT: I earlier said that `count = 0` needed to be moved.  Actually, looking more carefully it seems like the line `count = count + 1` line just needs to be moved under the `while` loop.